# What is the best practice to arrange android layout?

Tags: android, layout

I want to arrange my android layout like layout with image view and two seek bar top of the screen and two horizontalscrollview bottom of the screen top to another. But seems that layout doesn't arrange properly, here is my layout codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/editor_gradient"
    tools:context=".EditorActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:foreground="@drawable/blacklight_gradient"
            />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbarSize"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:progress="50"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbarRotation"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-170dp"
            android:progress="50"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/down" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/editor_footer" >
        </include>

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/down">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/iconContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

can anybody help me to organize my layout top to bottom order?

Comment: With these types of questions, it's usually advantageous to post an image of what you are expecting and what you are getting.

Comment: You have image for this type of view ?

Comment: seems everyone is thinking what im thinking - show us a visual mock of the screen you are trying to achieve

Comment: I can't post here the screen because I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/editor_gradient"
    tools:context=".EditorActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:foreground="@drawable/blacklight_gradient"
            />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbarSize"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:progress="50"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_below="@id/backimg" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbarRotation"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-170dp"
            android:progress="50"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekbarSize" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/editor_footer" >
        </include>

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl"
        android:layout_above="@id/down">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/iconContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```